# Concatenate mongo db fields while aggregating java

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection having following documents -

```
    {"_id":ObjectId("xxx"),"article_Id":"1","publish_Time":NumberLong(10)}  
    {"_id":ObjectId("yyy"),"article_Id":"1","publish_Time":NumberLong(11)}  
    {"_id":ObjectId("zzz"),"article_Id":"1","publish_Time":NumberLong(12)}
```

I want to aggregate on article_id and desired result is somewhat like -

```
  {"_id":{"articleId":"1"}, pub_t:[publish_Time":NumberLong(10),publish_Time":NumberLong(11),publish_Time":NumberLong(10)]}
```

I want to combine the publish_time field in separate documents to one array in resultant.
How can I do this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Were you able to use the query I provided in my answer?

Comment: I used $addToSet. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

#### Query

```js
db.articles.aggregate(
{
    $group:
    {
        _id:
        {
            articleId: "$article_Id"
        },
        pub_t:
        {
            $push: "$publish_Time"
        }
    }
})
```

#### Result

```js
{
    "_id" : {
        "articleId" : "1"
    },
    "pub_t" : [
        NumberLong(10),
        NumberLong(11),
        NumberLong(12)
    ]
}
```